# Message persistence in Topic

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I had question that whether a message will be persisted in a topic or not and I got most of my answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825196/can-topic-messages-be-made-persistent-in-activemq).

But how about this situation - suppose broker has started fresh, and some publisher has started sending messages to a topic, now in future some durable subscriber will get connected with this topic but currently there are no durable subscriber so in case of broker restart all messages sent by the publisher to that topic till now will be lost?

I tried above situation and indeed all messages were lost. Also, I tried this situation - I had an active durable subscriber and it was able to get messages pushed to the topic, then it got down and meanwhile more messages were pushed to the topic, then broker restarted and in the end all those delta messages were lost.

So, this basically means that in case of TOPIC message cannot be persisted because in contrary to the answer in that post I have mentioned earlier, having a durable subscriber has no effect because if there is active durable subscriber then message will be immediately consumed by it, and if there is no active durable subscriber and broker restarts then messages are getting lost.

So, bottom line is that in case of TOPIC message cannot be persisted or am I wrong in my understanding/tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of clarity is needed here.

1) Broker with no subscribers - All messages are discarded by the broker.

2) Broker with on-line durable subscriber - Messages (both persistent and non-persistent) are delivered to subscriber's storage, typically a queue, which are then consumed by the subscriber.

3) Broker with off-line durable subscriber - Messages (both persistent and non-persistent) are delivered to subscriber's storage. If broker goes down, all non-persistent messages are lost. However all persistent messages are recovered when broker restarts.

4) Broker with on-line non-durable subscriber - Messages (both persistent and non-persistent) are delivered to consumer. If subscriber goes off-line, no messages are delivered to consumer and no messages are cached by broker.

IBM MQ provides an option, called `Retain Publication`, to keep a copy of the latest message published on a topic. This way any late joiners will get this latest message.

Answer (score 2):

For a clean broker start where there are no offline durable subscriptions on the Topic in question the broker does not persist messages even if they are sent with the delivery mode of Persistent.  If you then add a durable subscription message that are sent as persistent will be written to the store and if the durable subscription is offline they will be held until consumed, or removed if there is a durable subscription consumer that is reading and acknowledging them.

If you are not sending the message with the delivery mode of Persistent then they will never be persisted, even if there is an existing durable subscription.  And once the durable subscription is unsubscribed the broker goes back to not storing Topic messages even if they are marked as persistent.

Given the behavior you are seeing the best guess is that your delivery mode on the send is non-persistent.